# Kubernetes pod is not created with tier label

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have tried to create a simple pod like below in minikube

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
        name: test-pod
        labels:
          tier: frontend
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Minikube told It created succesfully

```
pod/test-pod created
```

But when I checked with `kubectl get pod` I cannot found `test-pod`. I also try `kubectl describe test-pod` It notifies pod is not existed

```
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "test-pod"
```

I also check for event `kubectl get event`

```
5m40s       Normal   Pulling            pod/test-pod                Pulling image "nginx:latest"
5m37s       Normal   Pulled             pod/test-pod                Successfully pulled image "nginx:latest" in 2.807s (2.807s including waiting)
5m37s       Normal   Created            pod/test-pod                Created container nginx
5m37s       Normal   Started            pod/test-pod                Started container nginx
2m41s       Normal   Killing            pod/test-pod                Stopping container nginx
20s         Normal   Scheduled          pod/test-pod                Successfully assigned default/test-pod to minikube
```

It's stranger why pod is not created. If I remove label `tier: frontend`

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
        name: test-pod
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Or changed to custom label like this

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
        name: test-pod
        labels:
          mylabel: frontend
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Pod is succesfully created and I can see `test-pod` with `kubectl get pod`

As I understand Labels are intended to be used to specify identifying attributes of objects that are meaningful and relevant to users, but do not directly imply semantics to the core system

So can anyone explain for me role of label `tier: frontend` and Why I cannot create pod with this label ?

UPDATED: as comment of @TalRofe, I change value of label `tier: frontend` to `tier: test`, It worked well but I still don't understand problem here

UPDATED2: With help from @TalRofe comment, I figured out problem. I have a replicaset existed in my cluster like this

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: ReplicaSet
    metadata:
      name: myapp-replicas
      labels:
        app: myapp
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      replicas: 3
      selector:
        matchExpressions:
          - {key: tier, operator: In, values: [frontend, backend]}
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: myapp
            tier: frontend
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nginx
            image: nginx
            ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

If I remove this replicaset, I can create pod with label tier: frontend well. It seems this replicaset control cluster and allow only 3 pods with label tier: frontend.

Thank @TalRofe for your help

Comment: I just copied your first example and applied it to my cluster and it works flawlessly. the pod is running and has the tier: fronend label

Comment: What if you modify the value of the label `tier` to some random string?

Comment: @TalRofe If I modify value of the label `tier`  to random string, I works well

Comment: Is it the only resource you create in your environment? Obviously there is some another resource related with the `frontend` value. K8s didn't hardcoded any code related with `frontend`, for sure

Comment: @TalRofe Thank you, I have a Replicaset with that label value. If I removed that RS, I can create pod with label `tier: frontend`

Comment: @Bùi Đức Khánh , for the better visibility of the community you can post the resolved steps as an Answer.